# I can't start ubuntu after changing partition in windows

Tags: partitioning, root

I have a computer with dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
When I created the partitions for ubuntu I also created one extra partition to share files between the two OS's. 
I wanted to get more space for ubuntu partition so I deleted the shared partition but I did it in windows. Now every time I try to enter ubuntu it doens't start and goes to emergency mode. Can you please help me?

This is what appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwoFA.jpg

Comment: What happens exactly? Grub emergency mode? Or initramfs shell prompt? There is a large difference.

Comment: @AlexP I think its initramfs but im not sure. I added a printscreen to the post, take a look

Comment: It's initramfs. Did you by any chance add a `fstab` entry for the partition which was then deleted?

Comment: @AlexP not manually at least. But I did create the partition and then add install Ubuntu. Isn't it possible that Ubuntu itself added an fstab entry ?

Comment: Boot from the installation media, choose "Try Ubuntu", mount your root file system partition under `/mnt`, `sudoedit /mnt/etc/fstab`, check whether there is a line mounting that partition and if yes remove it, unmount `/mnt`, reboot.