# Cant install ubuntu and fix grub

Tags: grub2, partitioning

Until very recently I had two operating systems in my computer, Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10.

In Ubuntu, I had 3 partitions one mounted with `/`, other with `/home` and another for `swap`. In windows I had the usual ones.

I had one additional partition to share files between the two operating systems.

I wanted to get more space to the Ubuntu partition so (stupidly) I deleted the shared partiion because I thought I could expand, as in Windows, the Ubuntu partition. Then suddenty I couldn't use Ubuntu anymore.

I looked online on how to solve the problem and ended up trying very different approaches without successful results. I even asked a question here in [Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858191/i-cant-start-ubuntu-after-changing-partition-in-windows), but as I am a newbie I got confusing solutions.

Finaly, I gave up and deleted all Ubuntu partitions and tried to install Ubuntu all over again but, it still didn't work. As I couldn't install or uninstall Ubuntu I uninstalled grub online because I thought to myself that that might be the problem. After doing that I created a live usb for ubuntu and tried to use boot repair. This is what I got: http://paste2.org/PHnYZbC3

Answer (score 0):

Try booting into Ubuntu from your boot menu. It says at the end,

```
Boot successfully repaired.
You can now reboot your computer.

paste.ubuntu.com ko (), using paste.debian
paste.debian.net ko (), using paste2
```

Just go into BIOS and see.

Comment: When I try booting into ubuntu from my boot menu I get a grub minimal bash

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can boot into the live USB and run `sudo update-grub` and it will automatically find the partitions and update the Grub installation assuming it doesn't encounter any missing partitions etc.

**To be clear OP said he wants partitions deleted**

What I think has happened is your partition table has been "recovered" by something - maybe when it was deleted by one the other thought it was corrupted and "fixed" it. I encountered this a while ago when I was deleting my entire partition table.

My solution was to create a new empty FAT32 partition that took up my entire drive and the run the Ubutnu installer telling it to delete everything. Running Gparted and deleting the partitions manually would cause the installer to hang and rebooting I would find the partitions in my table again.

Comment: If you have multiple disks you may have to tell it what disk to update, like this `sudo update-grub /dev/sda` but be careful to make sure `/dev/sda` contains the disk you expect before you do anything to it.

Comment: but when I do 'sudo update-grub /dev/sda' for example it deletes all files in that partition? Why do I have to be carefull?

Sorry for deleting the comment, not on purpose

Comment: `update-grub` is fairly smart and will check to make sure the drive is what is expected, but in theory if you pointed it to a drive that doesn't have grub data in it it could read the wrong thing and "update" it incorrectly. Assuming you don't keep your files in ext3 partitions under a folder called "boot" it's likely safe to run, but we can't assume that.

Comment: Outputs the exact same error